# How to use of dynamic local template variable inside [ngClass] and ngIf

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have the following HTML component in angular 4:

```
<div  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
            <select 
              class="form-control form-control-sm" 
              name="durationTime{{i}}" 
              required 
              [(ngModel)]="item.durationTime"
              #durationTime{{i}}="ngModel"
              [ngClass]="{'is-valid': durationTime{{i}}.valid && durationTime{{i}}.touched, 'is-invalid': durationTime{{i}}.invalid && durationTime{{i}}.touched}">
                <option [ngValue]="null" disabled  selected>Elige</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of durationTimes" [ngValue]="item"> {{item}} </option>
            </select>
            <small *ngIf="durationTime{{i}}.invalid && durationTime{{i}}.touched"
              class="form-text text-muted-error">
                !Debes seleccionar una opción!
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to validate the controls but I have this error:

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 25 in [{'is-valid': durationTime{{i}}.valid && durationTime{{i}}.touched, 'is-invalid': durationTime{{i}}.invalid && durationTime{{i}}.touched}] in
```

My question is how to use of local template variable inside [ngClass] and ngIf in angular 4?

Comment: don't you think your scenario is suitable for reactive form?

Comment: Not. I have seen a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to give a different name to the [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) in each iteration of the `ngFor` loop. Just give it a normal name, like `#durationTime`. The `ngClass` binding and the `ngIf` condition will use the instance of the variable specific to the iteration of the loop.

```
<div  *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <select 
      class="form-control form-control-sm" 
      name="durationTime{{i}}" 
      required 
      [(ngModel)]="item.durationTime"
      #durationTime="ngModel"
      [ngClass]="{'is-valid': durationTime.valid && durationTime.touched, 'is-invalid': durationTime.invalid && durationTime.touched}">
        <option [ngValue]="null" disabled  selected>Elige</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of durationTimes" [ngValue]="item"> {{item}} </option>
    </select>
    <small *ngIf="durationTime.invalid && durationTime.touched"
      class="form-text text-muted-error">
        !Debes seleccionar una opción!
    </small>
  </div>
</div>
```